# Не открывает папку Process.Start()

Tags: c#, winforms

Не открывает папку.
Как будто ее на существует.

```
public void ShowPersonFiles(Object person)
        {
            if (person is Candidat)
            {
                if (((Candidat)person).FilesFolderPath == null) 
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("У даного кандита нет файлов");
                    return;
                }

                string folderPath = 
                    (Application.StartupPath + ((Candidat)person).FilesFolderPath);
                folderPath = folderPath.Replace(@"/", @"\");
                folderPath = folderPath.Replace(@"\\", @"\");

                try
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(folderPath);
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(folderPath);

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Вариант с `Process.Start("explorer.exe", folderPath);` дает то же самое.
Папка точно существует!

При чем если прописать в лоб путь к папке `Process.Start(@"C:\......");` - ее открывает.

Вот так выглядит `folderPath`

[image: folderPath local]

Вот ошибка

[image: erroe message]

Есть идеи как это решить???

Comment: Может, путь у вас "не склеился" все-таки правильно. Сравнивали `folderPath` с эталоном?

Comment: @АлексейСаровский сравнивал все сходиться.
Вот реальный путь к файлу 

`C:\Users\Borya\Desktop\sergeyChernuy\program\program\bin\Debug\data\files\all\27.12.2016\Borya`

И вот сгенерированный путь

`C:\Users\Borya\Desktop\sergeyChernuy\program\program\bin\Debug\data\files\all\27.12.2016\Borya`

Comment: @B.Harholinskiy может путь слишком длинный? положите например на диск C: - C:\data\files\all\27‌​.12.2016\Borya и попробуйте

Comment: *При чем если прописать в лоб путь к папке `Process.Start(@"C:\......");` - ее открывает.* Ну так сравните в чём разница между явно прописанным путём и тем, что получается в переменной `folderPath`.

Comment: @PetSerAl я с этого начал, прежде чем писать сюда. Никакой разницы.

Comment: @B.Harholinskiy То есть `string.Equals(@"C:\......", folderPath, StringComparison.Ordinal)` возвращает `true`?

Comment: Попробуйте прописать пусть по юниксовому ( path/filepath/file... ) Виндовс и так и так хорошо понимает

Comment: О май гад! У меня есть забавный случай в логе моего софта:"Не удается найти указанный файл, файл ошибки:C:\Documents and Settings\****\Local Settings\Temp\ReportTest26092433.xlsx|есть" вот это |есть - это проверка File.Exists! И такая беда всего на одном компьютере из 70! Я думаю, у него просто файл занят другим софтом в момент создания, т.е. антивирь пытается проверить мой excel файлик. Возможно у вас похожая проблема.

Comment: а хотя, у вас в лоб если прописать открывает.. Тогда другая проблема) Не дочитал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все оказалось очень просто! Ошибка - моя не внимательность при создании БД и попытке найти ошибку .

У меня путь к папке записывается в `nchar(n)` из за этого к концу строки в БД всегда добавляется куча пробелов.

Просто изменив на `nvarchar(MAX)` проблема ушла!

Всем спасибо!!!